# What should I use for git user.name?

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to Git and have never used any VCS before. I just opened a GitHub account. I started out by reading the GitHub help pages. I downloaded and installed Git on my local Windows machine. From there, I was directed to the Pro Git book. During the initial setup I used my proper legal name.

I've done so much reading about Git and GitHub in the last little bit that I can't remember where I read what. I thought I read something somewhere (but can't find it now) that said I should use my GitHub *username* as my Git *user.name*. So now I am not sure what to do.

I've read [this Pro Git page](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) which says:

> $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"

And I've read [this GitHub page](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) which says:

> $ git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"

The first implies that one should use their proper name, the second is unclear. However, the GitHub page also has the following to say:

> We use the email address to associate your commits with your GitHub account.

What I take from that is that the *user.email* is important if I want my commits linked to my GitHub account. Since it doesn't say anything about the name, I'm thinking that maybe it doesn't matter.

So what should I be using for my Git *user.name*?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but most people use their full name. Please close this question.

Comment: Whatever you want to appear in the commits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use your proper name, username or whatever identifier you'd like for user.name. It will be logged in each commit along with your email address, commit message and various other details. And you're exactly right about how GitHub uses the email address. Good luck with git! You're on the right track with Pro Git.

Answer (score 1):

As the field says, use it for your name. You can set your email in the *user.email* settings key. Github also uses email for displaying your global avatar image from the Gravatar service. I prefer to set my full name / email in global config, but you can set project-specific config, too. By default with all your repos will use the global setting (e.g. "John Doe"), unless you explicitly override it with a local setting (e.g. toxalot).

Answer (score -1):

There is 'user.email' for the email.
I use both, and they both get logged in the commits.